# How to get users in User-object of PrincipalType "Group"

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have a (Azure AD-group) that only shows up as a user

```
var userThatIsActuallyAGroup = myWeb.EnsureUser("MyAzureADGroupName");
var isGroup = (userThatIsActuallyAGroup.PrincipalType.ToString() =="Group")//"true"
```

So, How do I find/list the users in this group?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Graph API which has enough feature to satisfy your needs. 
Below Rest API endpoint helps you to get all the members of the AD group.

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups/{object_id}/$links/members?api-version
```

Please refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/groups-operations#GetGroupMembers).

Answer (score 0):

Graph API is the answer

**Option 1 - Two REST Calls**

1. Get all groups using REST call - `https://graph.windows.net/{tenant_id}/groups`
2. Find the object id of the group in question (MyAzureADGroupName)
3. Once you have the object id - fire another call to extract the members - `https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups/{object_id}/$links/members?api-version`

**Option 2 - Single Call**

1. If you know the object id of group then you can have a single call to this endpoint `https://graph.windows.net/contoso.com/groups/{object_id}?$expand=members`

More on this you can read here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/groups-operations

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Ill appove it as soon as I have time to test/verify it.